# Stick knot questions: simple but may not be easy

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, knot-theory, stick-knots

I have a few questions about nonplanar "stick circuits" (or hexagons and higher $n$-gons) that you might be able to help with:

(I know that $n=6$ is the minimum number of points to form a stick knot.)

1. Given $n=6$ points in $\mathbb{R}^3$ in general position connected by a specific "stick circuit" (nonplanar hexagon), what test can be done to see if it forms a stick knot vs. an unknot?
2. Given $n=6$ points in $\mathbb{R}^3$ in general position, there are 60 different stick circuits connecting them. True or false, at least one forms a knot?
3. Given $n=6$ points in $\mathbb{R}^3$ in general position, does the minimum-length stick circuit on these $n$ points ever form a knot? ("knotted 6-point traveling salesman problem with return)

All these can be generalized to $n > 6$.

These questions occurred to me over the last few days. I suspect (1) has a known answer but I have no idea about (2) or (3).

Comment: For (2), no. Take the six points to be approximately the vertices of a regular octahedron.

Comment: Actually, a regular octahedron (or close to it) is a configuration where I would always expect a stick knot.  A pentagonal pyramid (or close to it) would be more challenging.  Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2012.06.09

Comment: For (1) I know no simple test. However, all my mental images of 6-stick nots involve a stick with two acute angles at either end.  I imagine this is a necessary condition.  Gerhard "Or My Imagination Is Limited" Paseman, 2012.06.09

Comment: If the knot consists entirely of edges of the octahedron (or any other convex polytope) then it is a Jordan curve in that convex surface, therefore unknotted. The other possibilities can easily be handled case by case. 

Comment: (3) was asked a few days ago on m.se, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/154385/tying-knot-theory-with-traveling-salesman-problem-tsp

Answer (score 10):

The answer to question (2) is

- no for $n=6$,
- yes for $n=7$.

For $n=6$, take, for example, the following six points as vertices of a straight-line (stick) embedding of $K_6$:

$A = (-2,-2,1)$, $B= (2,-2,0)$, $C= (0,2,0)$, $D= (-1,-1,0)$, $E= (1,-1,1)$, $F= (0,1,2)$

The projection onto the $xy$ plane has crossing number $3$.

[image: a projection of K_6 with crossing number 3]

Moreover, the crossings are between disjoint pairs of edges. Therefore, since every nontrivial knot has at least three crossings, there is at most one possible cycle that could form form a nontrivial knot; that is, the cycle $AECDBF$ formed by the six edges participating in the crossings. But by the above-below relations at the crossings, this cycle clearly forms an unknot.

---

For $n=7$, [Conway and Gordon](https://doi.org/10.1002/jgt.3190070410) proved that every embedding of $K_7$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$ contains a Hamiltonian cycle forming a nontrivial knot, using the parity of the sum of the quadratic terms of the Conway polynomials of the Hamiltonian cycles as an invariant.

**Edit:** See also [J. L. Ramírez Alfonsín, Spatial Graphs and Oriented Matroids: the Trefoil, Discrete and Computational Geometry 22:149--158 (1999)](https://doi.org/10.1007/PL00009446)
for the following stronger result:

> > Every stick embedding of $K_7$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$ contains a Hamiltonian cycle forming a (left-handed or a right-handed) trefoil.

Answer (score 1):

A partial test for (1) is provided by the [Fary-Milnor theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fary%25E2%2580%2593Milnor_theorem). See also [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/54919/).

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem about matching red and blue dots in the plane in pairs by straight line segments, with a length minimal matching involving no crossings.  I imagine (3) could be answered negatively by similar reasoning.

Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2012.06.09

Answer (score 0):

A paper by [Gerard Venema and Tom Clark](http://www.calvin.edu/~venema/pdfs/Six-Chains.pdf) classified stick knots with 6 segments (using the lengths of the segments); they are using chains for their knots.

Comment: I realize now that you're looking specifically for circuits - my apologies.