# Knotted TSP tours in 3D?

Tags: pr.probability, mg.metric-geometry, discrete-geometry, knot-theory, stick-knots

In the plane, the Euclidean TSP tour never crosses itself—it is always a simple polygon.
I am wondering if there is a similar constraint for the Euclidean TSP tour
of points in $\mathbb{R}^3$.
To be specific:

> ***Q1***. Might it be true that the TSP tour of general-position points in $\mathbb{R}^3$ is never knotted, i.e., always the trivial knot?

That's probably too much to hope for. "General position" could take a number
of forms, e.g., no four points coplanar.

Suppose you
generate $n$ points uniformly at random within a sphere in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

> ***Q2***. What is the probability that the TSP tour is knotted?

---

[image: TSp100]

          

<sup>Unknotted TSP tour of $n=100$ points.</sup>

---

This is slim data, but for $n=50$ points, none of <strike>25</strike>
$50$ random trials resulted in
a knotted TSP tour.

Comment: For contrast, see the earlier MO question, "[Complexity of random knot with vertices on sphere](https://mathoverflow.net/q/54412/6094)."

Comment: For ignorants like me: TSP = Travelling Salesman Problem. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem

Comment: @YCor: Apologies, and thank you for the link.

Answer (score 8):

The answer is yes (or: the answer to ***Q1*** is *No*—*JORourke*), if you distribute sufficiently many points evenly along a knotted curve of say length one, that is the center of a knotted, self-touching torus. If the minor radius of the torus is $r$ and the distance between points, that are adjacent along the curve, is shorter, then the sequence of points along the curve resembles the optimal tour, which is of course knotted.

For randomly distributed points the answer may however be different.

Comment: Convincing, especially when the spacing along the curve is much less than $r$. Thanks!